# How to get gcc LTO work with library archives?

Tags: gcc, linker, archive, lto, gcc-plugins

gcc experts,

I'm trying to use gcc lto with library archives, as the gcc comes with my system (RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.7) doesn't work with -flto (neither for my Ubuntu 14.10), so I build binutils && gcc from scratch.

Here is what I did:
1. Build binutils-2.22 with `--enable-plugins`
2. Build gcc-4.7.2 with `--with-plugin-ld=/path/to/ld/built/in/step1  --enable-lto`
3. Then for the following simple test:

```
// 1.c:  
int foo(void)  
{ return 0; }  

// 2.c:  
extern int foo(void)  
int main(void)  
{ return foo(); }
```

The following can get `foo()` inlined:

```
my_gcc -O3 -flto -c -o 1.o 1.c  
my_gcc -O3 -flto -c -o 2.o 2.c  
my_gcc -O3 -flto -o a.out 1.o 2.o
```

While the following can't:

```
my_gcc -O3 -flto -c -o 1.o 1.c  
my_gcc -O3 -flto -c -o 2.o 2.c  
my_ar cr --plugin <my_gcc>/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/liblto_plugin.so 1.a 1.o  
my_ar cr --plugin <my_gcc>/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/liblto_plugin.so 2.a 2.o  
gcc -O3 -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -o a.out 1.a 2.a
```

As the building system for the product I'm working on has to use archives, then what I can do to let lto work with library archive?

Your help will be much much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In 2015 you should have built GCC 4.9 or GCC 5.1

Answer (score 2):

When linking, the order in which the libraries are listed on the command line, matters. So when compiling from the archives, you should swap 1.a and 2.a:

```
gcc -O3 -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -o a.out 2.a 1.a
```

I tested with gcc 4.9.2 and the disassembly, obtained with `objdump -d a.out`, shows that `foo()` is being inlined.